# Anylogic: Track AGV distance with Logging

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to track the distance travelled of different path-guided AGVs using the Logging feature. Unfortunately no movement stats of the AGVs are logged. I tried turning off the logging of other agents of the system, but that didn't help. The AGV agents are logged in the agents_log, but no movement stats are saved. Does anyone have an idea where there might be a problem?

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that movement stats are gathered for transporter fleet agents (cf. resource pool agents or other agents moving via `moveTo` instructions, `MoveTo` blocks, or being moved by resource agents).

At least in 8.7.2 nothing seems to be logged both for path-guided (e.g., the Solar Panel Production Line example model) or free-space (e.g., the Transporters Moving in Free Space example model).

I would check with AnyLogic support to see if this is either a bug in 8.7.2 or a limitation of movement capture in AnyLogic.